# Unexpected error when using selectExpr in databricks

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I already have a pyspark dataframe. I'm passing the variable to **selectExpr** in databricks to create new dataframe with column names that I need.
When I pass direct column names with aliases into selectExpr I don't have and error as a result my new dataframe successfully has been created. On the screenshot I have my columns with aliases
[image]

But when I try to pass into selectExpr exactly the same column but with variable I got en error:
[image]
Where did am I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a `sql_pattern` is a string of all column aliases, you can split it into a list of strings, using `split` function:

```py
pivotDF = clean_df.selectExpr(sql_pattern.split(","))
```

Comment: I've tested your approach and I faced the same error.
But I've found the solution(at least for me). 
I added to the selectExpr(sql_pattern.split(",")) and put my sql_pattern  as string.
I assume this expression converts into list under the hood by itself.

Comment: Ah, so `sql_pattern` in your case was just a string - sorry, that wasn't obvious from the description. A `split` indeed, should do the job - I will update the answer accordingly.